# Can I stop a service synchronously?

Tags: android, service

I need to stop a pair of services just before I delete a database.  The services are accessing the database, and if they are not stopped, the app will crash.

Like so:

```
stopService(new Intent(CurrentClass.this, FirstService.class));
stopService(new Intent(CurrentClass.this, SecondService.class));
CurrentClass.this.deleteDatabase(MyDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
```

As far as I know, the problem is that stopService is asynchronous.  How can I force my services to stop before my database is deleted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know,  the exact timing of the service being destroyed is up to Android and may not be immediate..so keeping this in mind... i think it is better that you **check in your service if your database is available**.. and then access it...if you think.. you shouldn't be doing this checking if databse is available,always ,in the service... then before you call

```
stopService(new Intent(CurrentClass.this, FirstService.class));
stopService(new Intent(CurrentClass.this, SecondService.class));
```

broadcast an intent that service is asked to stop and in your service implement a listener ,and in onreceive of that listener start the method for checking if the database is available.... like this.. for example..

```
 //this is in your service..
 bool stopping=false
 .......

 if(stopping)
  {
   //check if your databse is available and access it
  }
 else{
   //access your database directly..
  }
```

and in onreceive of your broadcast receiver

```
   @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
  stopping=true;
   }
```

Comment: I got it to work by using this idea a little more simply.  I just check to see if my database is open before I access it in the critical place, which worked for me.